# Try to match a regex pattern in text always returns None Python

Tags: python, regex

I have a regex defined in python and I am trying to extract a matching text using python. But it always returns None.

This is the configuration file text which is defined as `myConf.conf`

```
input {
  name: "abc",
  age: "20"
}

filter {
  name: "pqr",
  age: "25"

if [message] =~ "TRANSACTION:request" {
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}]  %{LOGLEVEL:level} \{% {DATA:logtype}}
        }

        map['method'] = event.get('method')
        map['request'] = event.get('body')
    }

    drop {}

    aggregate {                
        task_id => "%{tid}"
    }
}

output {
  stdout{}
}
```

This is my python code. It reads data from the myConf.conf file and try to match the defined regex

```
import re

path = "./myConf.conf"
file = open(path, "r+")
text_val = str(file.read())

pattern = re.compile(r"^filter\s*\{[\w\W]+?\n\}$")
result = pattern.search(text_val)
print(result)
```

No issues in the regex. It works fine
[Working regex](https://regex101.com/r/0SHjXz/10)

I am a Java programmer and totally new to python programming. What I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the multiline flag:

```
pattern = re.compile(r"^filter\s*\{[\w\W]+?\n\}$", re.MULTILINE)
```